# start-dfs.sh -not working - localhost: Bad port 'localhost' (Hadoop 2.7.2)

Tags: hadoop2

When i try the command hadoop version - its working fine.
hadoop namenode -format command is also working fine
The command start-dfs.sh - not working
I am getting
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: Bad port 'localhost'
localhost: Bad port 'localhost'
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]

Please find the below configurations files, Thanks.

core-site.XML

```
 <configuration>
   <property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>
     <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
 </configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
 <configuration>
   <property> 
     <name>dfs.replication</name> 
     <value>1</value> 
   </property>
   <property> 
     <name>dfs.permission</name> 
     <value>false</value> 
   </property>
   <property> 
     <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name> 
     <value>/home/.../hadoop-2.7.2/hadoop2_data/hdfs/namenode</value> 
   </property>
   <property> 
     <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name> 
     <value>/home/.../hadoop-2.7.2/hadoop2_data/hdfs/datanode</value> 
   </property>
 </configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
 <configuration>
   <property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
     <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

hadoop-env.sh

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

mapred-site.xml

```
 <configuration>
 <property>
 <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
 <value>yarn</value>
 </property>
 </configuration>
```

hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   arun

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

bashrc

```
#adding this

export HADOOP_HOME=/home/arun/my_work/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/arun/my_work/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"


export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin"


export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin 
export HADOOP_PID_DIR=/home/.../hadoop-2.7.2/hadoop2_data/hdfs/pid
```

While runing the command ./sbin/start-dfs.sh getting following error.

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: Bad port 'localhost'
localhost: Bad port 'localhost'
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: Bad port '0.0.0.0'
```

Comment: you  solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I faced and fixed by following the below steps,

1) ssh localhost should get a response. If not please install ssh and close all the terminals, restart the ssh and then execute the start-dfs.sh from /etc/sbin
2) check for HADOOP_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true in hadoop-env.sh

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes hadoop keep old configuration files in cache, I have faced these type of issues many times. Even though your configuration files look fine to me, I have a doubt that you may have given "localhost" as port number by mistake initially and tried to start hdfs. Later you did fix configuration and tried restarting hdfs, but your old configuration was still in cache. Restarting server should help.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking HADOOP_SSH_OPTS in your hadoop-env.sh and probably other locations. I had the same issue and the reason was that I had some uncompleted parameter in HADOOP_SSH_OPTS like

```
export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-p"
```